# Chai test if object keys are contained in a set of keys

Tags: javascript, chai

Is it possible to check with Chai if object keys are contained in a fixed set of keys (less properties should return ok and extra properties should fail).

Something like:
`expect(actualObjectKeys).to.be.contained.in(expectedKeysArray)`

I tried `have.keys` but actual and expected must be the same.
Also tried with `expect(actual).to.include.keys(expected)` but it returns ok if it has more keys.

I just looped on expected keys and checked each one of them to make it work, but I want to know if there is a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.include(val[, msg])](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_include) language chain and [.members(set[, msg])](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members) method.

> Add `.include` earlier in the chain to require that the target’s members be a superset of the expected members.

E.g.

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('60829224', () => {
  const obj = { a: '0', b: '1', c: '2' };
  it('should pass if the fixed set of keys has less key', () => {
    const actualObjectKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    expect(actualObjectKeys).to.include.members(['a', 'b']);
  });

  it('should not pass if the fixed set of keys has extra key', () => {
    const actualObjectKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    expect(actualObjectKeys).to.not.include.members(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
    expect(actualObjectKeys).to.not.include.members(['a', 'd']);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  60829224
    ✓ should pass if the fixed set of keys has less key
    ✓ should not pass if the fixed set of keys has extra key


  2 passing (19ms)
```